# Pass app to Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been running a Xcode project on my iPhone but I haven't upload the binary yet. The thing is that I've lost the code on my Mac (that's what happens when you don't commit con GitHub) and the only thing I still have from the project code is the "app" that the iPhone saved when I run it for the first time. Is there any way to pass the code from the iPhone or see the code?

Comment: Check trash/recovery tool might be get back

Comment: I think you can use the backup software to recover your folders.I used one of the s/w called as a disk drill pro http://www.cleverfiles.com/

Answer (score 1):

No. Your code was compiled, linked and packaged to produce the application, and it is the resulting compiled binary that has been installed on your phone.

You may be able to retrieve resources (storyboards, XIBs, images, plists...). For the code, there may be decompilers (not sure if there are any for Objective-C or Swift, though), but they will not reproduce your original code, just code that compiles to the same thing (i.e. without comments, with arbitrary names for local and instance variables, etc.).

Don't you have a Time Machine backup of your project?